# Messing with the iteration in a for loop

Tags: python, iteration

I am just a beginner programmer and just wanted to ask if it is acceptable/good code to mess with your iterator in a for loop.
Example(python):

```
 For i in range(n)
 if _statement_:
       i -= 1
       ...
```

I am not having a problem or anything, my code seems to work just fine like this but I am not sure if this counts as "good" code.

Comment: it wont do anything to your actual iteration, it will just make `i` reference some other variable. ie, it will still run `n` amount of times, regardless of what you set `i` to equal to

Comment: Apart from that you have syntax issues. A missing `:` after `range(n)` and a missing intendation for the `if` block

Answer (score 0):

You do not mess with iterator - you simply create a variable of the same name and do something with it

```
>>> for a in range(5):
...   print id(a)
...   print a
...   a -= 1
...   print id(a)
...   print
... 
24822128
0
24822152

24822104
1
24822128

24822080
2
24822104

24822056
3
24822080

24822032
4
24822056
```

As you can see these are **different** variables and the loop obviously iterates 5 times.

Is it a good practise? **No**. It is something counterituitive as one should expect that inside a loop, "a" means the same in each line. You should name your variable differently, like

```
>>> for a in range(10):
...   print a
...   b = a - 1
```

If you want to actually affect the number of repeats loop does you should use `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've given is acceptable, but not particularly productive. Your loop will run the same number of times, whether or not you modify `i`.

```
>>> for i in range(5):
>>>     i = i - 1
>>>     print(i)
-1
0
1
2
3
```

When you modify the variable `i`, it creates a new one, separate from the one controlling the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think modifying the current value of your iterator is fine and is just as a new variable. But I wouldn't recommend modifying the iterator itself like

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in my_list:
    my_list.append(i+4)
```

Would generate an infinite loop